# How to setup firebase auth local persistance?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to implement a method to locally persist my firebase auth session
Using the following method:

```
firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL
```

And this is my current implementation

```
constructor(public af: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router, public afs: AngularFirestore ) { }

logIn(email, password) {

this.af.auth.setPersistence(firebase.app.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL).then(() => {

  this.af.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((user) => {

    this.mailOutput.emit(email);

    this.router.navigate(['/pokemonlist']);
  }).catch(function (error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
      alert('Wrong password.');
    } else {
      alert(errorMessage);
    }
    console.log(error);
  });
});
```

}

I'm receiving an error

> 'firebase' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.

So I change the call to

```
this.af.auth.setPersistence(this.af.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL).then(() => {

  this.af.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((user) => {  ....
```

And now I receive the following error

> Property 'Auth' does not exist on type 'Auth'

How do I implement that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by importing:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```